# How can I share code between ansible action plugins

Tags: python, ansible

I am developing some ansible action plugins to interact with host-related settings (a monitoring API, not currently supported in ansible modules).

As I move from a single module to multiple modules, it's clear to me that some functionality needs to be shared, for example, the authorization dance needed, or unwrapping requests.

Some functionality is API specific and can go into a pip-installable python module to wrap access to the API.

Some other functionality is very ansible specific. The API needs a chunk of header session/token data since the site will deny access if you keep requesting a token and don't use the current unexpired one - so this should be stored in a well-known place in the ansible facts, such that all the plugins related would access it from the same place.

Simply putting an adjacent python file and importing it into the action plugin code won't work - I think there is some magic going on with how action plugins end up being loaded by ansible when used in roles or playbooks.

So other than pushing the ansible specific part of this back into the API wrapper python library, is there any way I keep code in a collection to share with multiple action plugins?

Comment: *You can enable a custom action plugin by either dropping it into the `action_plugins` directory adjacent to your play, inside a role, or by putting it in one of the action plugin directory sources configured in [ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings).* https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/action.html#enabling-action-plugins I guess this answer the question, so, the right path to go would be to create your own [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html).

Comment: Hmm - not quite answering the question. I've already been creating custom ansible action plugins. And I've gotten them to run (in a role for one, in a play for the other). This question is about how to share a bit of code between those plugins.

Comment: Ok I think that's your last two sentences that got me confused then. So you are not looking at the Ansible common part (that could fit in a role) but rather to deduplicate the Python code of your action plugin?

Comment: That's it. I'm thinking how I could better phrase that...

Comment: Can you use a class and put common functions in the class ?

Comment: You could put them in a class, but you still can't import the class. It seems that in the ansible context the python import mechanism/path is doing something different here. Ie - a relative `from . import <mymodule>` doesn't work, and absolute ie `from roles.<myrole>.action_plugins.<mymodule>` doesn't work either.

Comment: Building a collection might be a solution, then the usage can be borrowed from [there](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/blob/a2b775ece0b3f46d44bfd204a01d36d9fe6a0232/tests/unit/modules/utils.py#L6) but collection are only as of 2.10

Comment: And there they go `from ._some_file import something` https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/3e9943bc5e7a9cd393757aa8100d7fed80bd316e/lib/ansible/utils/collection_loader/__init__.py#L8

Comment: They do internally - but it looks like your module is loaded with bytes - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/e05c62547b3d547ffb433d1cf66e82b353f24262/lib/ansible/plugins/loader.py#L768 - 
```with open(to_bytes(path), 'rb') as module_file:
    module = imp.load_source(to_native(full_name), to_native(path), module_file)
```

Comment: I think that you could make it work by reusing ansible's own plugin code. You'd stick all of your common code in a utilities file and then use Ansible's plugin loader to dynamically import your utility file as if it were a module and then use that to access your code.

It would be ugly, but would probably work. I may pursue that approach myself if I get the time.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing this because I needed it. This worked for me in Ansible 2.9 and 2.11. You create a utilities plugin named `my_utils` like this:

```py
from ansible.errors import AnsibleError
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase
from ansible.utils.display import Display


class ActionModule(ActionBase):
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        raise AnsibleError("my_utils is for shared code, not for actual execution")

    def do_something(self, val: str) -> str:
        return val + ' hi'
```

Then in your other plugins you do this:

```py
from ansible.plugins import loader
from ansible.plugins.action import ActionBase

class ActionModule(ActionBase):
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        if task_vars is None:
            task_vars = dict()

        result = super(ActionModule, self).run(tmp, task_vars)

        utils = loader.action_loader.get("my_utils", self._task, self._connection, self._play_context,
                                         self._loader, self._templar, self._shared_loader_obj)
        stuff = utils.do_something(self, "someval")
```

I have not tested it yet, but I think that with the new collections infrastructure you can import other plugins like this:

```py
from ansible_collections.ansible.netcommon.plugins.action.network import (
    ActionModule as ActionNetworkModule,
)

class ActionModule(ActionNetworkModule):
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
```

Or you can create a module_utils library in your collection and use that instead, see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections_structure.html#module-utils

```py
from ansible_collections.community.test_collection.plugins.module_utils.qradar import QRadarRequest
```